# organising Fabric's command list output

Tags: django, fabric

I have a Fabric fabfile.py with a long list of commands (and growing). When I go `fab -l` I can't see the top of the command list. Grouping the commands under headers wouldn't make the list any shorter but it would make skimming the list easier - rather like the output of Django's `./manage.py help` command. Has anyone solved this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Fabric's "new style" tasks, you can take advantage of [namespaces](http://fabric.readthedocs.org/en/1.2.2/usage/tasks.html#namespaces). When you list your tasks, you can provide the [`-F` (`--list-format`)](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.6/usage/fab.html#cmdoption-F) argument, providing `nested` as the value, which will list the available tasks in a nested fashion, by namespace, the appearance of such is [documented here](http://fabric.readthedocs.org/en/1.2.2/usage/tasks.html#nested-list-output).

Fabric's "nested" task listing isn't quite as neat looking as Django's management command separation that lists commands by app in a very neat fashion, but it's a start.

Comment: hey - thanks for this! I had forgotten I had posted it. New style namespaces for Fabric looks about right.